# I tried to use "Transform translate" to center a div but it my div is up the page than center

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Basically this is the css code.

```css
.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">
</div>
```

If you put it in a code editor it does not give me a centered div. Why?

Tried to use transform to center div from a video but did not get results.
Link to video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooc6f1w6Mzg&t=54s

Comment: There are several ways to center elements with css, flexbox grid etc etc. just make some search on SO or Google.... N.B. il''see your box centered

Comment: what does  il''see your box centered mean

Comment: Also searched google didn't really understand what they said.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want, for example centered on which element?? maybe posting an imag of what do you expected

Comment: You have one mistake - you need the object, once it's been positioned 50% from the top of its container, to be moved back up by 50% of its own height, hence the 50% in the translate should be -50%. But the other problem is that you haven't defined a height for a parent container (is this to be body?) so the system doesn't know what the top: setting means.

Comment: Please explain A Haworth

Comment: Centered on the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace position: relative to position: absolute and give a minus sign before last 50%.

```
.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent-div{
position: relative,
height: 100vh
}

.login-box{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform :translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-div'>
<div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>
<div class="textbox">

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">

</div>

<input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is: Because `top/left` positioning does not apply to elements with `position: relative`, you need to use `position: absolute` to make those work. Alternatively (without using absolute positioning), you could use flexbox (see second example). Another factor impacting the vertical centering is of course the height of the container. To center it within the page (vertically), the container needs to fill the entire viewport, which it doesn't by default.

This is closest to your code:

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.login-box {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>

<div class="textbox">

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">

</div>

<input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

</div>
```

here is an alternative approach using flexbox (the flexbox container can be any wrapping element, doesn't have to be the `body`):

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}
.login-box {
  background: white;
  width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
      </div>

<div class="textbox">

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">

</div>

<input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">

</div>
```

Comment: Why did margin 0 auto work solely

Comment: What do you mean by view port

Comment: The view port is the physical screen.  margin: 0 auto set the top and bottom margin to 0 and the left and right margins to auto. Auto just lets the browser figure it out. If you set both left and right margin to auto, it tries to make them both the same length and.. voila! it put the div in the centre.

Comment: the margin: 0 auto; is acutally not even needed when using the absolute positioning.

Comment: Here's an explainer for margin: auto https://youtu.be/Azfj1efPAH0

Comment: Changing it to position absolute did not help'

Answer (score 0):

You can easily center a div with display flex.

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.login-box {
  width:280px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">
</div>
```

Comment: I trying to understand how to use position please not flex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hello replace below css in `.login-box` class.

```
width: 190px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: What???! Please, explain.

Comment: translate(x, y) can accept two values, not translateY(y) like you have it though.

Answer (score 0):

Position: relative positions the element relative to its parent. The parent has 100% width because it's the body but its height is only the height of the content (which in your case is the `login-box` div). So when you set `top: 50%` what you're doing is to set the `login-box` 50% down its own height. Then transform moves it the rest of the way.  In order to centre the div vertically you have to let the browser know how high the body element is and you can do this using `min-height: 100vh`.

Also using position: relative on the body sometimes not give you the position you want, it's better to use position: absolute. There's a good [video](https://youtu.be/P6UgYq3J3Qs) and [here](https://youtu.be/86nTToBm2uQ) from Kevin Powell on this.

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  }

.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.explainer {
position: absolute;
background-color:yellow;
padding: 0.25rem;
margin: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='explainer'>This red box is your body and you can see it doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the screen</div>

<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">
</div>
```

To make the thing position in the center just set the body height as follows:

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.explainer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">
</div>
```

But with modern css it's far easier to use something like grid:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.login-box {
  width: 280px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="" value="">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type="button" name="" value="Sign in">
</div>
```